# Issue in XML type column in SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a `VIEW`in SQL which has a column type of XML. The definition of `VIEW`is as follows.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_RequestDetails]
AS
    SELECT     
        r.RequestID, r.CompTypeID, ct.Name AS CompType, 
        r.LibID, r.Status, r.StateID, r.History, 
        r.LogID, r.ClosedDate, s.Closed AS StateClosed, 
        r.SubmissionDate, r.SubmitterUID, 
        (submitter.LName + ', ' + submitter.FName + ' ' + submitter.MiddleInit) AS SubmitterName, 
        r.ModifiedDate, r.ModifiedByID, r.LockStatus AS Lock,
        (modifier.LName + ', ' + modifier.FName + ' ' + modifier.MiddleInit) AS ModifierName,
        (SELECT AttributeName AS '@key', AttributeValue AS '@value'
         FROM dbo.View_RequestAttributes ra
         WHERE ra.RequestId = r.RequestId 
         FOR XML PATH('Attribute'), ROOT('RequestAttributes')) AS RequestAttributes,
        dbo.fnGetRequestProjectName(r.RequestID) AS ProjectName, 
        dbo.fnGetRequestProjectPriority(r.RequestID) AS ProjectPriority
    FROM    
        dbo.Request AS r 
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.State AS s ON r.StateId = s.StateId 
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.ComponentType AS ct ON r.CompTypeID = ct.CompTypeId 
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.UserInfo AS submitter ON r.SubmitterUID = submitter.UID 
    LEFT JOIN
        dbo.UserInfo AS modifier ON r.ModifiedByID = modifier.UID
```

The XML value generated for the column has some invalid characters like (`&#x01;&#x09;`..etc)due to the value from the table columns that this view is generated.

Is there any way that we can restrict the XML type column to generate a Well formed XML?

Or do we need to parse in our code behind to make the XML valid and display to the user?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
(SELECT AttributeName AS '@key', AttributeValue AS '@value'
     FROM dbo.View_RequestAttributes ra
     WHERE ra.RequestId = r.RequestId 
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'), ROOT('RequestAttributes')) AS RequestAttributes,
```

to this (You need the `TYPE` extension to let the sub-select come back with "real" XML)

```
(SELECT AttributeName AS '@key', AttributeValue AS '@value'
     FROM dbo.View_RequestAttributes ra
     WHERE ra.RequestId = r.RequestId 
     FOR XML PATH('Attribute'), ROOT('RequestAttributes'),TYPE) AS RequestAttributes,
```